# MongoDB: Dos consultas db.restaurants (name, adress,borough...)

Tags: mongodb

3. Nombre de los restaurantes (name) de cocina portuguesa (cuisine toma el valor Portuguese) y que se encuentran en el barrio de Queens (borough).

db.restaurants.find( {"cuisine": "Portuguese", "borough" : "Queens"}

4. Nombre (name) y dirección (adress) de los restaurantes que tienen alguna valoración (grades.score) mayor de 90

db.restaurants.find( {"grades.score": {$gt: 90 } } ).pretty()

Si introduzco estos códigos me salen las consultas, pero ¿hay algún modo de hacerlas de manera más exacta con lo que pide?

Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, respecto a su pregunta, con "más exacta" ¿se refiere a obtener únicamente los campos "name" y "address" en la segunda consulta?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *exacta*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma predeterminada, las consultas en MongoDB devuelven todos los campos en los documentos coincidentes. Para limitar la cantidad de datos que MongoDB envía, puede incluir un documento de proyección para especificar o restringir los campos a devolver.
Para ello, debe agregar como segundo parámetro a la llamada de la función find su documento de proyección.

### Ejemplos

Para únicamente obtener los nombres (name) en la primer consulta debería utilizar este comando:

```sh
db.restaurants.find({ "cuisine": "Portuguese", "borough" : "Queens" }, { "name": 1 })
```

Para únicamente obtener el nombre (name) y dirección (address) en la segunda consulta el comando debería ser:

```sh
db.restaurants.find({ "grades.score": { $gt: 90 } }, { "name": 1, "address": 1 })
```

- Referencia: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: Muchas gracias, es que me faltaba saber la parte del segundo comando que hay que introducir.